# Submit button doesnt work after opening through Gsheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am currently switching from a VBA and trying to make the impossible possible in Google Sheets.

My whole project is to make an script that opens a form in the sidebar/ popup window after clicking a button and saves the values inserted to the form in some sheet. From what I have learned and read here, I have managed to get it into the following condition:

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(),
      cell = sheet.getCurrentCell(),
      val = cell.getValue(),
      col = cell.getColumn(),
      row = cell.getRow();
  if (col === 7 && row > 7 && val !== 'Description: ') {
    // ui.alert('OK');
    launchForm();
  } else
    ui.alert('Wrong row selected');    
}


function launchForm() {
  var formID = '1OHk3sHIoxZm0__eRHfVBsOxwPCgQARYHCnzC3O6B_3Q';
  var form = FormApp.openById(formID);
  var formUrl = form.getPublishedUrl();

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formUrl);
  var formHtml = response.getContentText();

  var htmlApp = HtmlService
      .createHtmlOutput(formHtml)
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setTitle('NEW RECORD')
      .setWidth(500) 
      .setHeight(450);

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(htmlApp);
}

function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Launch Form",
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Custom Menu", entries);
};
```

**Everything works fine however the Submit button on the form is not working at all and the inputs are not recorded. Anyone could possibly help?**

I believe getting over this would help me to finish the whole project.

Comment: Do you have HTML code?

Comment: Hi, no i do not. Don't exactly know how this works. However it opens the new browser window with the Gform loaded. Just the submit button does not do anything...